# Given transition matrix for Markov chain of 5 states, find first passage time and recurrence time

Tags: matrix, probability, markov-chains

Transition matrix for a Markov chain:

```
0.5  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.2 
0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.5
0.0  0.4  0.4  0.2  0.0 
0.3  0.0  0.2  0.0  0.5 
0.5  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.3
```

This is a transition matrix with states `{1,2,3,4,5}`.  States `{1,2,5}` are recurrent and states `{3,4}` are transient.  How can I (without using the fundamental matrix trick):

- Compute the expected number of steps needed to first return to state 1, conditioned on starting in state 1
- Compute the expected number of steps needed to first reach any of the states `{1,2,5}`, conditioned on starting in state 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the fundamental matrix, you can do two things:

1. Create a function that simulates the Markov chain until the stopping condition is met and that returns the number of steps. Take the average over a large number of runs to get the expectation.
2. Introduce dummy absorbing states in your transition matrix and repeatedly calculate `p = Pp` where `p` is a vector with 1 in the index of starting state and 0 elsewhere. With some accounting you can get the expected values that you want.